# How to: Stop ListView from rebuilding video_player widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have managed to get a video to play on flutter-web, however, when I scroll the video in the ListView will rebuild/reload.

How can I stop the video_player (in the ListView) from being rebuilt when I scroll?

Sorry for the lengthy code sample.. I'm not sure how to condense it further

Any help would be great! Thanks

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../widgets/video/chewie_video.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(height: 1000),
          Center(
            child: ChewieVideo(
              videoPlayerController:
                  VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/video.mp4'),
            ),
          ),
          Container(height: 1000),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class ChewieVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
  final bool looping;

  ChewieVideo({
    @required this.videoPlayerController,
    this.looping,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChewieVideoState createState() => _ChewieVideoState();
}

class _ChewieVideoState extends State<ChewieVideo> {
  ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: widget.videoPlayerController,
      autoInitialize: true,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      looping: widget.looping,
      errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            errorMessage,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Chewie(
        controller: _chewieController,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    widget.videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I think I know what the problem is... If I replace the ListView with a SingleChildScrollView then the website doesn't crash... If so, does this mean that it's because the Widgets are being created and then destroyed? I'm using a CustomScrollView along with a SliverList in my real project ... Is there any way to stop the CustomScrollView/SliverList from destroying the widgets?

Comment: So, removing the dispose method in the ChewieVideo class stop the website from crashing...

Not sure if I'm supposed to do that, can anyone figure out another workaround?

Comment: God I want to give up... It works on Chrome, and Firefox on Windows, and Firefox on Android, but it won't work with Chrome on Android...

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: I'm not sure what I've done but I think I've fixed it... I will post my working code anyway and hopefully anyone who has problems will be able to fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a good or just temporary fix but this is how I have managed to get it to work...

If you are using inside of a ListView/CustomScrollView, then you need to adjust the `cacheExtent` for either of these widgets... I have set mine to 1000.

I'm not quite sure what's happening but it works...

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: primaryBlack,
      drawer: NavDrawer(),
      body: Scrollbar(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          cacheExtent: 1000,
          slivers: <Widget>[

...
```

after doing that chewie and video_player plugins shouldn't rebuild/refresh inside of a ListView

Comment: what about if we are using pagination in listview, we cannot replace it with customScrolls